# Can't understand the use of window.onscroll = null in React

Tags: reactjs

What's the use of window.onscroll = null here?
It shows no difference even when i comment that last line out.

```
const [isScrolled, setIsScrolled] = useState(false);

window.onscroll = () => {
    setIsScrolled(window.pageYOffset === 0? false : true)
    console.log(isScrolled);

    return () => (window.onscroll = null);
};
```

Comment: Is that the actual code? With a couple modifications (move it into a use effect, then move the return statement outside of window.onScroll) it would make sense to me, but as written, the window.onscroll = null appears useless.

Answer (score 0):

Removes the event handler added to onScroll event. But better to move it inside useEffect hook.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As written, the `window.onscroll = null` is useless. It will never be executed. However, this code is suspiciously close to code that *is* useful. The following code is what i would expect to see:

```
const [isScrolled, setIsScrolled] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
  window.onscroll = () => {
    setIsScrolled(window.pageYOffset === 0? false : true)
  };
  return () => (window.onscroll = null);
}, []);
```

In this modified version, `return () => (window.onscroll = null)` is returning a cleanup function for the effect. When the component unmounts, this function runs and removes the event listener. This is important to do so that you avoid memory leaks.